# Affordable, programmable device with gprs and simple sensors?

Tags: embedded

I've got quite a fun challenge / work assignment. I'm to monitor a couple of 5V light bulbs (warning lights) on a machine standing far out in no man's land. I'm looking for an affordable device with an input which allows me to hook into the light bulb circuit to tell whether it's lit or not.

Requirements:

- GPRS
- Inputs for at least two light bulbs
- Programmable in C or something similar.

Bonus (not required, but it would be kind a nice):

- Waterproof casing / chassis (I could make this my self, but it would be nice if I didn't have to)
- Option to add other sensors like humidity, temperature and gps.

Any tips?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd recommend an arduino

> Arduino is an open-source electronics prototyping platform based on flexible, easy-to-use hardware and software. It's intended for artists, designers, hobbyists, and anyone interested in creating interactive objects or environments.
>
> Arduino can sense the environment by receiving input from a variety of sensors and can affect its surroundings by controlling lights, motors, and other actuators. The microcontroller on the board is programmed using the Arduino programming language (based on Wiring) and the Arduino development environment (based on Processing). Arduino projects can be stand-alone or they can communicate with software on running on a computer (e.g. Flash, Processing, MaxMSP).

there's an article here on hooking one up with gps

http://www.arduino.cc/playground/Tutorials/GPS

and for more information on the arduino platform in general, and where to buy

http://www.arduino.cc/

**Edit:** just noticed you were looking mainly for GPRS and not GPS - doh, however, quick look on google brings up this: http://www.libelium.com/squidbee/index.php?title=New_GPRS_module_for_Arduino_%28Hilo_-_Sagem%29 which is a GPRS module for the arduino :]

Comment: GPRS isn't GPS, it's packet radio through the cellular system.  The Arduino can still do that on the cheap: http://www.libelium.com/squidbee/index.php?title=New_GPRS_module_for_Arduino_(Hilo_-_Sagem)

Comment: I've contemplated Arduino. I liked the Waspmote device from Libelium. It looks like it might save me some work compared to buying a "raw" Arduino board.

Answer (score 4):

Have you looked at [Arduino](http://www.arduino.cc/)?

Answer (score 3):

in fact, what you are asking already exists: many companies which produces electrical component for the industry provides a rail-mounted GPRS modem for remote signaling.

- here is [one example](http://www.phoenixcontact.com/signal-level-matching/31261_40428.htm), made by phoenix contact
- [another one](http://www.multicap.be/gsm-gprs-3g/gsm-gprs-modems/audiotel-gprs-industrial-i-o-modem) from another company
- the [tele-control range](http://www.wago.com/cps/rde/xchg/SID-53EFFEF9-C74DBCD7/wago/style.xsl/eng-19339.htm) of product from [wago](http://www.wago.com/)
- [telit](http://www.telit.com/) is well-known for its GSM chips, and provides [a complete module](http://www.telit.com/en/products/gsm-gprs.php?p_id=12&p_ac=show&p=2) with GPRS and programmable in python.
- you can find some fancier systems including GPS and linux-based, [here](http://www.m2mcom.be/akt-30) for example

there are countless other solutions...

Comment: Good point. It would probably be more robust than a DIY device--it's one thing to get something "working"; it's another thing to make it able to handle extremes of temperature, wind, being leaned on by cattle, power glitches. 50% of the code would probably have to be error handling to make it robust against every conceivable crazy thing that might happen.

Comment: On the other hand, DIY could be a very interesting project. Just be prepared to invest a lot of time to make it fit for purpose if it's being used on a real work site.

Answer (score 2):

I would buy the Terminus from [Janus RC](http://www.janus-rc.com/) it is based on a telit module. It is a cell modem with 9 GPIO and you can program it using python.

**Interface**

9 Bi-directional CMOS I/Os

Power Monitor

1 ADC

ITU-T V.24 serial link through UART

**Python Script Support**

Integrated Python script interpreter (V1.5.2+)

2 MB of non-volatile memory

1.2 MB of RAM reserved for Python engine usage

Powerful built-in libraries makes accessing hardware easy